# reasons for closing questions: off topic vs homework

Tags: discussion

I read [The "off-topic" close reason about homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/the-off-topic-close-reason-about-homework-questions) , agreed with the rationale behind it, and so I started to use "off topic" instead of "homework" when I found a question which seems like a homework question.

However, now I have some doubt. There are two different problems with homework questions: the first one is that somebody could use mathSE not to do their work, but the second is that it's difficult to help a bona fide poster to find the solution himself if we do not exactly know where he was stuck. The reason "missing context" comes close to show it, but at least for me it would not be clear.

So, could it be possible to reformulate the "homework" closing reason in a more positive way, something like "the community is happy to help you, but for giving an effective help you should reformulate your question explaining how did you arrive at that question, what do you know about it, and what did you try to solve it by yourself"?  (note that I did not use the word "homework" :-) )

Comment: Related: [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11075/43351). There is considerable support for removing the "homework" reason.